# Restrictions.Disjunction() between condition a AND condition b OR condition c AND condition d

Tags: nhibernate, detachedcriteria

How can I create a disjunction in NHibernate that would accomplish the following sql:

> Select * from MyTable
>   Where (conditionA = true AND conditionB = true) 
>   OR (conditionC = true AND conditionD = true)

From what I've seen, the Disjuntion() takes single criterions and "ORs" them together. Is it possible to group to criterion together and "OR" it against another pair of criterion?

I hope this question is clear enough.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not exactly pretty but you would write it like this :

```
.Add(
    Restrictions.Or(
        Restrictions.Conjunction().Add(Restrictions.Eq("columnA", true)).Add(Restrictions.Eq("columnB", true)),
        Restrictions.Conjunction().Add(Restrictions.Eq("columnC", true)).Add(Restrictions.Eq("columnD", true))
 );
                                                                )
```

Comment: I ended up doing it completely differently from this because of the dynamic nature of my query builder, but this does answer the question as stated. Thanks!
I used the operator overload features of nhibernate to create an AbstractCriterion and then added all the abstractcriterion to a Restrictions.Disjunction().

Answer (score 2):

You also can use

```
.Add(
     Expression.Or(
         Expression.And(Expression.Eq("columnA",true), Expression.Eq("columnB",true)),
         Expression.And(Expression.Eq("columnC",true), Expression.Eq("columnD",true)))
```